# Roadmap to advanced spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs

I have somewhat recently switched from neovim to spacemacs. After switching to the develop branch, taking some time to actually read the dotfile, reading the documentation of some layers, and adding some minor tweaks to some of them, I have gotten curious about learning more about emacs and spacemacs.

I am still a confused spacemacs user. When reading the [bibtex layer](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/bibtex/README.html), for example, I am still unsure whether I should carry out the installation of the org-ref and helm-bibtex packages and how (if at all) this installation should differ for spacemacs.

Anyway, overall, what would you recommend a beginner spacemacs user to read, do, watch, or whatever, in order to get a better grasp of spacemacs? I imagine that something important might be to learn some elisp, and I've taken a peek at the references in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/how-can-i-start-learning-emacs-lisp). Are these also advisable for spacemacs? What would you add?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: The question is too broad and invites primarily opinion-based answers. This is a question that's better aimed at a discussion forum, such as Reddit. On emacs.SE, and SE generally, we look for specific questions with specific answers, not for discussion, general advice, brainstorming ideas, etc.

Comment: The link @Drew provided has some good links to resources and learning paths.  This post also lays out paths: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/how-can-i-start-learning-emacs-lisp